# why display-inline block does not affect the block?

Tags: html, css

I am newbie with html css and here is my problem.

I code a nav and subnav at html file as this one

```
<div id="header">
        <!-- begin nav -->
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Bane</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tour</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="">More
                    <i class="nav-arrow-down ti-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="">Merchandise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Extras</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Media</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- end nav -->
        <!-- begin search-->
        <div class="search-btn">
            <i class="search-icon ti-search"></i>
        </div>
        <!-- end search-->
    </div>
```

And I want to make a block with color grey at block Merchandise, Extras, Media.
Here is my code at styles.css

```
#nav .subnav {
/*display: none;*/
position: absolute;
background-color: #fff;
min-width: 160px;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
}
```

My problem is, when I click to Merchandise, for example, the grey is not display fully all the block as I want. Here is the design [image: design picture]

But here is what I got [image: my problem's picture]

As you can see in the second picture, the block become fell in.

I thought that I can use display: inline-block; to solve this problem , but when I add this command to #nav .subnav, it does not solve this problem.

They said that, I can use at #nav .subnav this command `min-width: 160px;`, but it still not well.
Could you please give me some ideas for this problem?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give `width:100%` of ul tag.

```
<ul class="subnav" style="width:100%;">
                <li><a href="">Merchandise</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Extras</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Media</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).